# Searching a MongoDB collection based on another

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a `document` called `Mapping`, which has an `_id` and an array of objects called Mappings.
I have another `collection` called `NewMappings`. For each `_id` in `NewMappings`, I need to search within the array of `Mappings (of Mapping collection)` and return the `_id` of `Mapping`.

I wrote something like this, but it failed to return anything.

```
var d=db.NewMappings.find(); 
d.forEach(function(item){
    db.matching.find({Mappings: {$elemMatch : {TargetId: item._id}}})
})
```

however, this query returned values

```
var d=db.NewMappings.find(); 
db.matching.find({Mappings: {$elemMatch : {TargetId: d[0]._id}}})
```

Am I missing something?
Please help me.  I am in dark.  thanks in advance.

Comment: In the code where you are using forEach, you are creating a function that does not return a value. You need to store it or print it.

Comment: Can you please add a piece of code to show that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way, if you just want to see the results is:

```
var d=db.NewMappings.find(); 
d.forEach(function(item){
    db.matching.find({Mappings: {$elemMatch : {TargetId: item._id}}}).forEach(printjson)
})
```

You can also use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)

Comment: Thank you.  I assumed that the second find returns only one document. I added the forEach part and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to do a Join, which isn't explicitly supported in MongoDB. You'll need to either use a few aggregation functions to flatten the data or a mapreduce.

Here's an example using mapreduce to restructure information:
http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/pivot/